# Get table cell value based on the first cell content

Tags: javascript

I have a page with multiple dynamic tables , one of the table looks like the below structure

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    One  Two
2    b    15/12/2017
3    a    X
2    W    10/12/2014
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
<th>Col3</th>
</tr>
<tr> <td>1</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>15/12/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>2</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>15/10/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr> <td>3</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>15/09/2017</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to know How can I get the cell in `col3` with header name based on the value at `col1`?

**EX:**

I want to find the table by ID and check  its first cell for each row, if it equal 2 then get the cell value of `col 3` in the same row !

Any help would be fully appreciated

Comment: Can you please post your table markup so we can see how to extract the cell value?

Comment: It's generated table but i tried to add the main structure

Comment: Even if auto generated, if you copy parts of the **resulting** markup we can see what you have. There could be data attributes, classes or other we can use to make selection proper. It also helps if you could post any code you have so far so we can help fix your solution instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something with jquery like below snippet.

**Update:** you can get particular column by table header as well using `$('th:contains("col3")').index()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').find('tbody td:first-child').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '2') {
      console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq($('th:contains("col3")').index()).text());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>ONE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>TWO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>THREE</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, i have multiple tables and i need to work with a specific table ID

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery it's quite easy; if you've found the cell, get the row, and the third cell in that row;

```
$('td') // Select all cells
.filter(function() { // Filter the cells
    return $(this).text() == '2';
})
.closest('tr') // get the table row
.find('td') // select all cells in that row
.eq(2) // select the third cell (0-based index)
.text(); // this will output '15/12/2017'
```

**edit** I'm in a good mood today, check this little demo; https://jsfiddle.net/a32knb81/. Just input your search key in the input field an you'll get the value of the third column in that same row.

Comment: Thank you , How get with the header column name instead the column index, i don't know where col 3 order in he table

Comment: what do you mean exactly with the 'header column'? Give me the value you want to search for and what value you want to find.

Comment: the header column : col 3